Real-time text-to-speech with Deepgram on React Native
I am trying to integrate STT and TTS using Deepgram and my custom LLM stack with headers into my React Native app. But I am struggling to find proper streaming packages that may allow me to use packets vs. sending the entire file once it is ready.
Has anyone done this? Or if not, do you know of any React Native libraries dealing with TTS streaming? I think I found one for STT so far. I do want to be able to connect it to Deepgram or OpenAI Whisper since my models are trained for specific set of words.
I have heard of VAPI, but it is too costly.
